# Can't install gitlab (in centos 6)

Tags: centos, gitlab, yum

I try install gitlab-ce on CentOS 6.7(Final). but, failed.

My Environment

use proxy (set proxy in /etc/yum.conf)

my gitlab_gitlab-ce.repo file
 (https://packages.gitlab.com/gitlab/gitlab-ce/install manual configuration)

```
[gitlab_gitlab-ce]
name=gitlab_gitlab-ce
baseurl=https://packages.gitlab.com/gitlab/gitlab-ce/el/6/$basearch
repo_gpgcheck=1
enabled=1
gpgkey=https://packages.gitlab.com/gpg.key
sslverify=1
sslcacert=/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt

[gitlab_gitlab-ce-source]
name=gitlab_gitlab-ce-source
baseurl=https://packages.gitlab.com/gitlab/gitlab-ce/el/6/SRPMS
repo_gpgcheck=1
enabled=1
gpgkey=https://packages.gitlab.com/gpg.key
sslverify=1
sslcacert=/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
```

when excute install command, occur error

```
yum -q makecache -y --disablerepo='*' --enablerepo='gitlab_gitlab-ce'

https://packages.gitlab.com/gitlab/gitlab-ce/el/6/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] Peer cert cannot be verified or peer cert invalid
Trying other mirror.
Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: gitlab_gitlab-ce. Please verify its path and try again
```

What should I do ? Help me please.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you set this up manually? The install script does this for you.

Answer (score 0):

You first check Proxy setting of your system.
Fire below command:

```
yum update
```

if it wont work then set proxy in File: `/etc/yum.conf`
And then check.